# C# Converting Json List to List objects using JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am attempting to convert lists in Json (using Newtonsoft.json), to a custom "Element" structure, where I will have many classes all with a property named "Element" in it, but some arbitrary type.

An example used in the code below is this json:

```
{ 
   "List_A": [1, 2], 
   "List_B": ["Hello", "World"] 
}
```

In the first property "List_A", the numbers need to be converted into AΞElement class, that has a property Element of type int.

In the second property "List_B", these strings need to be converted into a different class BΞElement.

Below is working code where I am trying to fill in the ReadJson function of the ListConverter class I have created, that is a JsonConverter.   I am trying to figure out how to read stuff out of the serializer, and create my own custom objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    [DataContract]
    public class AΞElement
    {
      [DataMember]
      int _Element;

      public int Element
      {
        get => _Element;
        set => _Element = value;
      }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class BΞElement
    {
      [DataMember]
      string _Name;

      public string Element
      {
        get => _Name;
        set => _Name = value;
      }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class C
    {
      [DataMember]
      List<AΞElement> List_A { get; set; } = new List<AΞElement>();

      [DataMember]
      List<BΞElement> List_B { get; set; } = new List<BΞElement>();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var json = "{ \"List_A\": [1, 2], \"List_B\": [\"Hello\", \"World\"] }";

      var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings()
      {
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new ListConverter() }
      });
    }

    public class ListConverter : JsonConverter
    {
      public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
      {
        return typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
      }

      public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
        if (existingValue != null)
        {
          var list = (IList)existingValue;
          list.Clear();
        }

        var elementType = existingValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

        if (elementType.Name.EndsWith("ΞElement"))
        {
          /// What do I put here??
        }
        else
        {
          serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);
        }

        return existingValue;
      }

      public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: It is imperative that I keep the class structures of ΞElement and the json the same.

Comment: Is `Ξ` a valid character for naming?

Comment: yes. The code above is fully compilable, and can run. Test it out

Comment: Though use of that character, is just a minor detail of the issue at hand, as long as there is some key way to identify these classes I am dealing with.

Comment: That is a strange design. Why not simply use `List<int>` and `List<string>`? Seems like an [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have no choice, I must do it like this

Comment: The classes I cannot change, I am working with existing code, that i must deserialize into.

Comment: The code I posted is just a Minimum Verifiable Example of the problem I am trying to solve. -- The codebase is much bigger than this, and unchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I've come to a solution like this:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (existingValue != null)
    {
        var list = (IList)existingValue;
        list.Clear();
    }

    var elementType = existingValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

    if (elementType.Name.EndsWith("ΞElement"))
    {
        var list = (IList)existingValue;

        if (elementType.Name.EndsWith("AΞElement"))
        {
            while (reader.Read() && reader.Value != null)
            {
                list.Add(new AΞElement
                {
                    Element = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value)
                });
            }
        }
        else if (elementType.Name.EndsWith("BΞElement"))
        {
            while (reader.Read() && reader.Value != null)
            {
                list.Add(new BΞElement
                {
                    Element = (string)reader.Value
                });
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);
    }

    return existingValue;
}
```

Basically I'm checking for type of AΞElement and BΞElement, reading from JsonReader and adding the values in array one by one into the relevant list until no more tokens to read.

Comment: Ah so this is how you deserialize from the reader. Thanks. I'll have a look after i wake up in the morning